# UEFI Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams

Tags: python, uefi

I'm trying to run CHIPSEC in UEFI Shell
But on my HP 8300 SFF all I get when launching Python368.efi is this message

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Current thread 0x00000000 (most recent call first):
```

Same USB device tested on my old laptop seems to work, I can start Python368.efi
Any advice is welcome.

i read manual but can't find any solution.

I deleted **pycache** from \EFI\StdLib\lib\python36.8\encodings
to make a clean start.
Then started python358.efi -vv
and get this

```
calculate_path[856]: module_search_path = "F"
calculate_path[857]: prefix             = "F"
calculate_path[858]: exec_prefix        = "F"
calculate_path[859]: progpath           = "F"
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import _imp # builtin
import sys # builtin
import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'edk2' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _weakref # previously loaded ('_weakref')
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installing zipimport hook
# trying FS0:/Efi/StdLib/lib/python36.8\zipimport.py
# trying FS0:/Efi/StdLib/lib/python36.8\zipimport.pyc
# can't import zipimport
# code object from FS0:/Efi/StdLib/lib/python36.8\encodings\__init__.py
# created 'FS0:/Efi/StdLib/lib/python36.8\\encodings\\__pycache__\\__init__.cpython-36.pyc'
# wrote 'FS0:/Efi/StdLib/lib/python36.8\\encodings\\__pycache__\\__init__.cpython-36.pyc'
# trying FS0:/Efi/StdLib/lib/python36.8\codecs.py
# trying FS0:/Efi/StdLib/lib/python36.8\codecs.pyc
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams

Current thread 0x00000000 (most recent call first):
```

As I said in first message same storage device (tested on two laptops HP and Acer) works fine, Python368.efi start and works.
But in this PC don't.

Problem solved.
https://github.com/chipsec/chipsec/issues/1602#issuecomment-1362243716

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please include full traceback message - not just the first line.   It is likely that the problem in a file naming conflict.